# django - pass parameter from template to models.py' s function

Tags: python, django, templates, variables, models

I' ve a model called mymodel, which has a property getp, but this requires a parameter (request):

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    ...
    def getp(self, request):
        return "STH"
```

. From the views i pass the request and one model to the template:

```
return render_to_response('x.html', {
                                       'mymodel': Mymodel.objects.get(id=17),
                                       'request': request
                                   }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

, and from the template file is there any way to call the getp function with the request parameter? I know this shouldn' t be used like this, but my question is rather theoretical than practical.

Any workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

seems a duplicate of
[How to use method parameters in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529550/a-way-to-use-method-parameters-in-django-templates)

one solution would be to pass result of your method to template. something like:

```
object = Mymodel.objects.get(id=17)
return render_to_response('x.html', {
    'mymodel': object,
    'mymodel_getp': object.getp(request),
    'request': request
    }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

other solution would be to write a custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(name="model_getp", takes_context=True)
def model_getp(context, object=None):
    return object.getp(context)
```

and then in template:

```
{% model_getp mymodel %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, the first solution is how it should be used in a django way, but my problem with this solution is that what if i wanna pass more object to the template (Myobject.objects.filter()), and i want to  loop over them. One obvious solution would be to use tuples in the result, so like ((mymodel1, mymodel1_getp), (mymodel2, mymodel2_getp)), but this is ugly.

Comment: The second solution works fine, i like it (except that the simple_tag doesn' t accept the name parameter), but what if i' d like to test the existence of the result? At least in this form it doesn' t really work: {% if model_getp mymodel %} . It says unused 'mymodel' at end of if expression.

Comment: to use it in if statement you would have to make a filter out of it that evaluates to bool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047959/django-templatetag-evaluating-to-a-boolean i am not sure how to pass context to filter

Comment: I c. And what' s the "standard way" to solve my problem in the first scenario, when i return the required result from the views, because i think my tuple solution is very ugly.

Comment: However it' d be nice if the second solution would work with an if tag.

Comment: Please see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ there is nothing wrong with touples but i would set a model field 'p' for each object in the view instead. And the question is why do you need a request object to get something from your model? View should be something that binds model logic with request and prepares response. Ideally you model should not be aware of what 'request' is